# Can current FOP 1.1 version render overlay pdf

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

i try since some days to make an pdf overlay of an existing file with XSL-FO

here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="firstPage" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="25mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="firstPage">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block-container position="absolute">
                    <fo:block font-size="20pt" color="red">
                        blub </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
                <fo:block-container position="absolute">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:external-graphic src="file:///Users/gigo/Downloads/pdf-image/overlay.pdf"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

I try to use an old thread from an mailing list: [Link to Thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-fop-users/201011.mbox/%3CAANLkTinV80y9QmXH_gzLQkpkjdhpRUAR6EWDV9n_mn6K@mail.gmail.com%3E)

does this relay work with the current fop version. i am using mac OSX ? might be this the problem?

Are there other solutions to integrate existing pdf files?

Comment: How did you generate overlay.pdf? Can you show a full XSLT stylesheet? How does your current approach fail?

Comment: Does not work with FOP, but with RenderX it is as easy as <fo:region-before extent="11in" background-image="overlay.pdf"/>

Comment: And what product does i need for processing this on an linux server? does this convert the pdf to an image and integrate this?

Answer (score 0):

We have found an workaround for doing this.

so with "pdf2svg" it is posible to create from any pdf file an svg file. and an svg file kann be included as external-grafic. that works great with fop, so it not required to buy expensive render that offer that. only write some code, or convert the for example "letter paper" one time and than integrate the svg.